# Strange number inside Mini Cart

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I have a number appearing within each item listing of the Mini Cart:

[image]

Where would this be rendered?

I've looked in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart\sidebar\default.phtml` but can't see anything obvious.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the code from inspecting the element:

```
<p class="product-name">
  <a href="url.html">
    <strong>Naturtint Nutrideep Multiplier Protective Conditioner</strong>
    303
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: this may be an SKU, please do inspect element

Comment: @AnilSuthar I have edited my question, I can confirm that it isn't the SKU

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem, it was displaying the Brand ID for some reason.

Code was found here:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/package/template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml
```